# Theta functions identites

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, theta-functions

I have been reading Rick Miranda's Book on Riemann surfaces and to indroduce meromorphic functions on the complex torues $\mathbb{C}$\ $L$ he talks about theta functions. I was able to see that $\theta(z+1)=\theta(z)$ but I cant quite seem to see why $\theta(\gamma+z)=e^{-\pi i(\gamma+2z)} \theta(z)$, maybe theres some identity about series that i am not seeing, also I cant seem to show that the only zeros of $\theta$ are at the points $(1/2)+(\gamma/2) +m+n\gamma$.
The definition of this $\theta$-function is $\theta(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\pi i[n^2\gamma+2nz]}$.

Any help is aprecciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading [DLMF Chapter 20](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20) on Theta functions. There is an infinite product expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$$\theta(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\pi i[n^2\gamma+2nz])$$
we get
\begin{align}
\theta(z+\gamma)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\pi i[n^2\gamma+2nz+2n\gamma])\\
&=\exp(-\pi i\gamma)\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\pi i[(n+1)^2\gamma+2nz])\\
&=\exp(-\pi i\gamma-2\pi inz)
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(\pi i[(n+1)^2\gamma+2(n+1)z])\\
&=\exp(-\pi i\gamma-2\pi inz)\theta(z).
\end{align}

Comment: Oh yeah nice , thanks , do you have an idea about the part of the zeroes of the function?

Comment: @Something Integrate $\theta'/\theta$ over the boundary of a fundamental region.